# Is there no way to save the workspace in Python as its saved in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, python-3.x

Matlab allows you to save the workspace very easy by saving all the variables, objects, arrays, etc, For details read [save in workspace MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html).

Is it not possible to do that in python without having to resort to something annoying like a JSON file, or a CVS or any other annoying format that need to serialize myself or parse?

I just want something like:

```
save('file_name', ... variable names ...)
```

or

```
save('file_name') # save everything.
```

---

for example it should work with any objects, numpy libraries etc, just save my workspace and then let me load it back.

Comment: you can try to pickle your globals() and locals(), should work with most of the stuff.

Comment: If you are using IPython, you could use the magic %save

Comment: The `dill` package might provide for what you need: http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki/dill.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nice one!

Comment: You could use spicy.io --> sio.savemat http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/tutorial/io.html